# p:spinner p:ajax and f:param mixed together, bean method executed multiple times

Tags: ajax, dynamic, primefaces, spinner

I'm developping with Primefaces 4.0, JSF Mojarra 2.1.7 and jBoss_7.1.1_Final.

The tool I'm creating is mainly a dialog window showing a dataTable with dynamic columns (p:columns)

Those dynamic columns show a pSpinner like this :

```
                                        <p:spinner id="updateQj_#{colIndex}_#{rowQj.idQbt}" widgetVar="updateQjJs_#{colIndex}_#{rowQj.idQbt}" stepFactor="1" min="0" max="#{rowQj.qbtType}"
                                                    value="#{rowQj.quantiteDuJour(qjColonne.property)}" onkeydown="return false;"
                                                    styleClass="editQj" rendered="#{not verrouille}" title="Cliquez ici pour modifier la quantité journalière" >

                                            <p:ajax listener="#{recherche.updateQj}" update="@this, :formRecherche:growl" process="@this"/>
                                            <f:param name="idQbt" value="#{rowQj.idQbt}"/>
                                            <f:param name="jour" value="#{qjColonne.property}"/>
                                            <f:param name="ligne" value="#{rowIndex}"/>
                                            <f:param name="colonne" value="#{colIndex}"/>
                                        </p:spinner>                                        
                                </p:column>                                             
                            </p:columns>
```

Everything seems to be working fine till for some unknown reason, the click in one of the columns modifies the current value plus the one previously updated in another column. To see it clearly: if I keep clicking/updating spinners in the same column everything works fine. If I click a spinner of another column it updates both. Any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Tried using a newer PF version?

Comment: Yeah i would like to, just that it's not contractually possible...i'm so tired of that, thanks

Comment: You can always try. Just to see if it is fixed in a newer release. If it is, you can always try to patch your current version. I nowhere stated that you should use it in production

Comment: Finally, i made it! I overrided the embedded pf jquery.ui (1.10.3) with the jquery.ui 1.10.4, i then replaced p:spinner by a simple input followed with a jquery("input").spinner() (that simple command failed in 1.10.3 with the message 'spinner is not a function'. Some hack needed to trigger the change event, i'll post some code soon :). CHeers

Comment: Thanks Kukeltje for giving me the envy to patch primefaces, what seemed like an untouchable brick

Comment: Please create it as an answer. You can and are even encouraged to although it is not technically a PF patch but using a completely different jquery-ui with added spinner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in primefaces4, p:spinner in a cell made of p:columns>p:column doesn't behave like it should, first clicks work but at some moments, a simple click generates incessant ajax calls as if i clicked each spinner in each cell...After several days of workaround, and thinking that pf makes usage of jquery under the cover i tried by myself. Surprisingly, firebug console logged 'spinner is not a function' and jquery.ui.version was 1.10.3 so i downloaded 1.10.4 on jquery's site and included it in my header after other javascripts. jquery.ui.version showed 1.10.4 and no more error message appeared. :)
Finally, i wrote this in each p:column of p:columns in a p:datatable

```
    <input id="updateQj_#{rowIndex}_#{colIndex}_#{rowQj.idQbt}"    widgetVar="updateQjJs" class="editQj"     value="#{rowQj.listeDesQj[colIndex].quantiteRealisee}"> ‌​ 
</input> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    jQuery("input[id=updateQj_#{rowIndex}_#{colIndex}_#{rowQj.idQbt}]")
    .spinner‌​({  min:0, 
                max:#{rowQj.qMax}, 
                step:1, 
                change:function(){ rmt_updateQj([parameters]); } }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but please add some text on why you solved it this way, how and why you updated the PF jquery (like mentioned in the comments) and format the code so it is readable

Comment: In your answer please…  not as a comment